# why not $F(x,0)=x_0$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Definition of  contractible space

Let $F$ be the homotopy between $\mathrm{id}_X$ and $x_0$, that is $F:X\times [0,1]\to X$ is a continuous map such that
$$ F(x,0)=x,\quad F(x,1)=x_0$$
for all $x\in X$.

**My confusion** : I have some  confusion  with  $ F(x,0)=x$

why not  $F(x,0)=x_0$ ?

Here $f:[0,1]\to X$ is  a loop based $x_0$, we know that  loop is a path whose initial point is equal to its  terminal point

So i think $F(x,0)=x_0$

Comment: In general, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$, a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ is a continuous function $H : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. In your case, take $Y=X$, $f = \operatorname{id}_X$ and $g$ the constant map $x_0$.

Comment: Got it now  thanks u @azif00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of a homotopy between two functions $f, g : X \to X$ is that it's a continuous map $F : X \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(\cdot,0) = f$ and $F(\cdot,1) = g$.

If you set $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x_0$, then this becomes $F(x,0) = x$ and $F(x,1) = x_0$.